# Loewy series of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, noncommutative-algebra

I am studying the loewy series of module. But I can't understand how the series building.

I know that the socle is the sum of all simple submodules, but I can't understand the limit ordinal case.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?  The definition of a socle? The limit ordinal case? what?

Comment: @rschwieb I don't understand the definition of socle  series

Comment: I know, you said that already. I’m asking you what part of the definition is unclear. First of all, you should state the definition you’re asking about, rather than making everyone guess. Does it match the one in Wikipedia?

Comment: @rschwieb I know that the socle is the sum of all simple submodules, but I can't understand the limit ordinal case

Comment: That is a reasonable question. I edited it into your problem statement (which you should do yourself, next time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that the socle is the sum of all simple submodules, but I can't understand the limit ordinal case.

If you understand the part of the definition that says $M_{\alpha+1}/M_\alpha=\mathrm{Soc}(M/M_\alpha)$, then the thing to understand is that using this to inductively define the series, one successor at a time, cannot exceed the first limit ordinal above $\alpha$ (call it $\beta$.) You will get closer and closer to $\beta$, but not reach it.

So, there has to be a method for "leaping the gap" after defining all those things before $\beta$, and the way to do it is to take the union of all the $M_\lambda$ for $\lambda < \beta$. The result is $M_\beta$, which you've now defined for that limit ordinal.

Then continues the process with $M_{\beta+1}, M_{\beta+2},M_{\beta+3}\ldots$ and so on, but you cannot reach the next limit ordinal (call it $\gamma$) this way. You have to take the union over all $\lambda < \gamma$ of $M_\gamma$, and then you've got $M_\gamma$.

This process is called [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction) and it allows you to define $M_\alpha$ for every ordinal $\alpha$.

If you still have problems understanding transfinite induction, I invite you to read the wiki and or seek basic problems and answers about the topic.

Comment: Thank you very much. you are the best.